# None вместо единицы

Tags: python, python-3.x

На питоне не мог разобраться, почему там в выводе стоит то None, хотя если логически подумать, то эм, единица нет?

```
def func(y):
    if y==1:
        return y
    else:
        y-=1
        func(y)

print(func(2))
```

Comment: Ваша ветка `else` ничего не возвращает, поэтому по умолчанию там None

Comment: Надо `return func(y)`

Answer (score 0):

print() - печатает на экран то, что ей передали.  Ваша функция: "def func(y)" работает рекурсивно:

1. 2 !=1 --> идем в блок "else". Тут вычитаем 1 и вызываем снова функцию
2. 1 ==1 --->возвращаем значение y (В вашем случае это 1)
3. Возвращаемое значение из п.2 возвращается в блок "else" (в место вызова п.1) там Ваша функция ничего не возвращает (значит она стала процедурой, которая возвращает None), а просто заканчивает свое выполнение. Соответственно print() печатает результат, отчет работы функции (которая без return стала процедурой) "def func(y)", который вернул в точку вызова None. Поэтому print() печатет "None"

Правка для @Эникейщик:

[image: Правка для @Эникейщик:]

Comment: неточность у вас. В питоне функция, в которой нет return, возвращает None. Если бы функция ничего не возвращала, то print ничего и не напечатает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, Какая, если не секрет? Выше сделал правку, которой реализовал, Вашу логику. Как видите - возвращет None

Comment: И кстати, если функция ничего не возвращает, то это не функция, а процедура.

Comment: именно - возвращает None. Я так и написал  а называется это функция это или процедура  дело десятое и никого кроме оторванных от жизни теоретиков не интересует

Comment: @Эникейщик, я понял, о чем речь)) Действительно не правильно выразился. Правильнее будет так: Процедура в точку вызова возвращет None, Функция всегда возвращает в точку вызова результат свой работы. Если Функция, которая по окончанию работы ничего не вернула, значит она стала процедурой =))) Гыыы..